# How to fix ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2570)

Tags: python-3.x, openssl

I am a beginner programmer, I started making a telegram bot in python with the telebot library, and I ran into such a problem that when I started testing the bot from several devices at the same time, the bot stopped and gave an error

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/cloudshell-user/bar_5237_bot/bar_bot.py", line 71, in start
     self.user_data.set_id(id)
   File "/home/cloudshell-user/bar_5237_bot/utils/user_data.py", line 25, in set_id
     self.save_all_data()
   File "/home/cloudshell-user/bar_5237_bot/utils/user_data.py", line 72, in save_all_data
     self.google_sheets_api.update_user_data(user_info)
   File "/home/cloudshell-user/bar_5237_bot/google/google_sheets_api.py", line 139, in update_user_data
     body=body
   File "/home/cloudshell-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
     return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/home/cloudshell-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 932, in execute
     headers=self. headers,
   File "/home/cloudshell-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 222, in _retry_request
     raise exception
   File "/home/cloudshell-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 191, in _retry_request
     resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
   File "/home/cloudshell-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google_auth_httplib2.py", line 225, in request
     **kwargs
   File "/home/cloudshell-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1725, in request
     conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey,
   File "/home/cloudshell-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1444, in _request
     (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
   File "/home/cloudshell-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1396, in _conn_request
     response = conn.getresponse()
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1373, in getresponse
     response.begin()
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 319, in begin
     version, status, reason = self._read_status()
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 280, in _read_status
     line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
     return self._sock.recv_into(b)
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into
     return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/ssl.py", line 929, in read
     return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2570)
```

how can this be fixed? If the information is not enough, then ask.

Comment: Since you mentioned that the error occurs when you run the bot from several devices simultaneously, it's possible that the server is rejecting some of the connections due to the number of requests or rate-limiting. Additionally, running multiple instances of the bot on different devices may create conflicts when accessing and updating the Google Sheets data concurrently.